# Is there a better way to extract a href URL using CSS selector in Python?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm building a Facebook Reels Downloader script, and that's what I got so far:

```
from urllib.parse import unquote
import requests
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# create a requests session
session = requests.Session()

# set up the login credentials
username = 'username'
password = 'password'

# log in to the website
login_url = 'https://facebook.com/login'
session.post(login_url, data={'username': username, 'password': password})

# create CSV file for downloadable URLs
downloadable_urls_file = 'downloadable_urls.csv'
with open(downloadable_urls_file, mode='w', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(['download_url'])

# open CSV file containing URLs
with open('urls.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        url = row[0].strip().replace('www', 'mbasic')

        # get the download URL and save it to the CSV file
        try:
            response = requests.get(url)
            if response.status_code == 200:
                soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
                download_link = soup.select_one('div.widePic a')
                if download_link is not None:
                    download_url = download_link['href']
                    with open(downloadable_urls_file, mode='a', newline='') as f:
                        writer = csv.writer(f)
                        writer.writerow([download_url])
                    
                        print(f"URL Added to {downloadable_urls_file}")
                else:
                    print(f"Download link not found in {url}")
            else:
                print(f"Error getting download URL for {url}: status code {response.status_code}")
        except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
            print(f"Error getting download URL for {url}: {e}")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error getting download URL for {url}: {e}")
```

But sometimes it gets the URL and sometimes it doesn't, URLs seems to woks fine and videos are accessible. What could be the issue?

**That's an example of what it returns:**

Download link not found in https://mbasic.facebook.com/reel/139107278919319

URL Added to downloadable_urls.csv

Download link not found in https://mbasic.facebook.com/reel/1297902184128387

Download link not found in https://mbasic.facebook.com/reel/730695835506797

Download link not found in https://mbasic.facebook.com/reel/194058260037516